# How to create Shiny application (Rstudio) that requires user to select dataset and column name and then performs feature selection

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, r-caret, appcelerator-studio

I'm trying to build a application for myself to get every dataset in a folder, display those in a `selectInput()`, and then the column names from the data set in another `selectInput()`, so that when both values have been selected, it performs feature selection (with caret) and displays the output.

I've attached what I have done so far below, however I cannot test the `selectInput()` as the program closes itself as soon as its run with an error:

> Warning: Error in dataset: could not find function "dataset"
> [No stack trace available]

Here is the code:

```
#datasets <- list('Maccas' = read.csv("menu.csv"))
#selectInput("dataset", "Please pick a data set", choices = names(datasets))

#####################
library(shiny)
library(datasets)

ui <- fluidPage(sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("dataset", "choose a dataset", c("Maccas")),
    selectInput("column", "select column", "placeholder1"),
    selectInput("level", "select level", "placeholder2")
  ),
  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
))

server <- function(input, output, session){
  dataset <- list(read.csv("menu.csv"))
  
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "column", choices = names(dataset())) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$column, {
    column_levels <- as.character(sort(unique(
      dataset()[[input$column]]
    )))
    updateSelectInput(session, "level", choices = column_levels)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    subset(dataset(), dataset()[[input$column]] == input$level)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You are writing `dataset()`, but `dataset` isn't reactive, so just use `dataset`.

Comment: @Axeman, - just tried that. Still get the same error

Comment: perhaps update your question with current code that isn't working so we can reproduce. did you want your dataset as a `list` (as it currently is coded)? or just a data frame?

Comment: sorry to say this, but your code can't work and is not easily fixed. e.g., Why you read in a file rather than using `list.files`? Your second selectInput which should show column names has to be reactive. Thus, it must be specified on the server side.  And so on...There are so many issues that I will not provide an answer. I recommend to go back and check all examples on https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/